# Finding which IDs do not have a full year worth of data

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset (20+ years of telemetry data) and I am trying to understand if I am missing any days worth of data.

Using the example dataframe below:

```
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2004/01/01"), as.Date("2020/12/31"), "days"), each=4)
Animal_id <- rep(1:20, times=length(unique(dates)))
df <- data.frame(dates=dates, id=Animal_id)
df[,"Year"]<-format(df[,"dates"],"%Y")
```

This dataframe should be complete in that it has all the dates present, so if I remove some:

```
df <- df[-4, ]
df <- df[-6, ]
df <- df[-10, ]
df <- df[-15, ]
df <- df[-16, ]
df <- df[-20, ]
```

Now I want to figure out what dates I am missing and what animal ID these dates belong to. I have been using up to this point the following code:

```
FullSeqID <- seq.Date(from=min(df$dates), to=max(df$dates), by=1)
missingID <- FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% df$dates]
```

This will tell me what days I am missing data on, however I am trying to figure out what the ID is for the animal that is missing those days (and if it is just one that I can drop or multiple animals in which I will populate information for). Because of this I have also tried writing a loop to go through each year

```
df$combo<-paste(df$Animal_id,df$Year, sep = "-")
z<-split(df, df$combo)

missingID<-(NULL)

for (i in 1:length(z)){
  AnimalIDloop<-z[[i]]
  myDataDateID<-AnimalIDloop[,c("dates")]
  FullSeqID<-seq.Date(from = min(myDataDateID), to=max(myDataDateID), by=1)
  missingID<-rbind((FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% myDataDateID]),AnimalIDloop$Animal_id[2])
  
  ##rbind dataframe created with the column being AnimalID, Other columns = ##second part  
  ##pull out first value from the AnimalID column 
  
  ##missingID<-rbind(MissingID, new rows (above))
}
missingID
```

My goal is to use the rbind function to combine the dates I am missing from the FullSeqID with the corresponding ID column by taking out the first value of that column and putting this into the dataframe missingID created above.

This gives me the following output:

[1,]
[2,]

Which is not what I am trying to get it to say, and can't figure out where I am going wrong with my rbind function. I have also used the following loop which has worked, but I am making the mistake of writing over the missingID so it only outputs the last year where there are missing dates.

```
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  AnimalIDloop <- y[[i]]
  myDataDateID <- AnimalIDloop[, c("Date")]
  FullSeqID <- seq.Date(from=min(myDataDateID), to=max(myDataDateID), by=1)
  missingID <- FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% myDataDateID]
}
missingID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some `dplyr` approaches to this, which I think is a great tool for this sort of exploratory data analysis and cleaning:

```
library(dplyr)
```

How many rows are present for each id? We can see 3 & 4 have fewer:

```
df %>%
  count(id)

#  id    n
#1  1 1461
#2  2 1461
#3  3 1460
#4  4 1460
```

In case there might be duplicate rows of the same animal on the same day, we could add a de-dupe step to see how many *days* are present for each id:

```
df %>%
  distinct(dates, id) %>%  # dedupe multiple rows for one date & one animal 
  count(id)

#  id    n
#1  1 1461
#2  2 1461
#3  3 1460
#4  4 1460
```

We might also wonder which dates have fewer than max # of animals?

```
df %>%
  count(dates) %>%
  filter(n != max(n)) 

#       dates n
#1 2003-01-01 3
#2 2003-01-02 3
```

It sounds like you are most interested in getting a list of the missing animal-dates. There's probably a more elegant approach, but one way could be to make up some placeholder data (ie the "presence" column here), use `complete` from tidyr to add every possible date in the data to every possible id, and then to just keep the rows that weren't there originally, ie which don't have that placeholder. One shortfall of this approach is that it won't detect a date that is missing for all animals. The longer version below that would address that issue.

(If you only want to look at the range of data from each animal's first data to their last data, you could add a `group_by(id) %>%` before the `complete(dates = seq.Date...` step so that the dates are only filled in for that animal's range of dates.)

```
df %>%
  mutate(presence = "present") %>%
  complete(dates, id) %>%
  #complete(dates = seq.Date(min(dates), max(dates), by = "day"), id) %>%
  filter(is.na(presence))

## A tibble: 2 × 3
#  dates         id presence
#  <date>     <int> <chr>   
#1 2003-01-01     4 NA      
#2 2003-01-02     3 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already `split` your dataset, you may simply run the code you were using in a function in `lapply`.

```
y <- split(my_data, my_data$Animal_ID)
lapply(y, function(x) FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% x$dates])
# $`1`
# Date of length 0
# 
# $`2`
# Date of length 0
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "2003-01-02"
# 
# $`4`
# [1] "2003-01-01"
```

Or use it in `by` which combines `split` and `by` in a sense.

```
by(my_data, my_data$Animal_ID, function(x) FullSeqID[!FullSeqID %in% x$dates])
# my_data$Animal_ID: 1
# Date of length 0
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# my_data$Animal_ID: 2
# Date of length 0
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# my_data$Animal_ID: 3
# [1] "2003-01-02"
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# my_data$Animal_ID: 4
# [1] "2003-01-01"
```

Comment: this worked, HOWEVER, do you have a way where I can create (potentially) a dataframe or list including the results. My issue with this one is in my overall dataset I have 600+ different IDs and it seems quite a fair bit of them are missing information. I am unfortunately working with a dataset that was not well managed up to this point, and with so many missing its not been easy to go through this output

Comment: @MargaretHughes Could you perhaps show the expected output in an edit of your question?

Answer (score 0):

A alternative approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2003/01/01"), as.Date("2006/12/31"), "days"), each = 4)
id <- rep(1:4, times = length(unique(dates)))
df <- data.frame(dates = dates, id = id)

df <- df[-4, ]
df <- df[-6, ]

df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = id, names_prefix = "id_") |> 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("id_"), ~ is.na(.)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   dates       id_1  id_2  id_3  id_4
#>   <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2003-01-01     1     2     3    NA
#> 2 2003-01-02     1     2    NA     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>